# Segmentation fault in Scipy _fitpack fprank_() 

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, scipy

I ran a python code and I got the error just, "Segmentation fault". I then ran "gdb python" and re-run the code from the (gdb) prompt, and I got the following result:

```
#0  0x00007fffed573487 in fprank_ ()
    from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack.so
#1  0x00007fffed56ee81 in fpsurf_ ()
    from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack.so
#2  0x00007fffed55363d in surfit_ ()
   from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/_fitpack.so
#3  0x00007fffed54183a in fitpack_surfit (dummy=<value optimised out>, 
    args=<value optimised out>) at scipy/interpolate/src/__fitpack.h:217
#4  0x00000000004965f1 in call_function (f=<value optimised out>, 
    throwflag=<value optimised out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4013
#5  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (f=<value optimised out>, 
    throwflag=<value optimised out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:2666
#6  0x000000000049d325 in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (co=0x1cf50b0, 
    globals=<value optimised out>, locals=<value optimised out>, 
    args=<value optimised out>, argcount=<value optimised out>, 
    kws=<value optimised out>, kwcount=5, defs=0x1baaca0, defcount=16, closure=
    0x0) at ../Python/ceval.c:3253
#7  0x0000000000496a92 in fast_function (f=<value optimised out>, 
    throwflag=<value optimised out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:4109
#8  call_function (f=<value optimised out>, throwflag=<value optimised out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:4034
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
```

Can anyone help me sort out my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: There may be something faulty with your code. It would be helpful if you could post a minimal code segment that reproduces the error.

Comment: Looks like a problem with Scipy's fitting functions. Can you isolate the problem to a certain part of the code?

Answer (score 1):

From the traceback one can interpret that it is scipy native libraries which are crashing in fprank_() function.

It is most likely a scipy bug. Contact scipy community and/or file a bug against scipy with an isolated test case.

It is unlikely you will find a solution in stackoverflow.com, because it is clearly a crashing bug.